# MySQL query optimization - not using primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a query using three tables. This query is part of a larger query that is killing performance due to the full table scan on the Patients table caused by this seemingly simple query.

The query's purpose is to be able to see a list of patients with the doctor name, the treatment and the amount charged for a given day.

I have already created an index on PatientID in Transactions and an index on DoctorID in Patients, but MySQL insists on a full table scan for patients.

Patients tables (13,000 rows)

```
CREATE TABLE `Patients` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `DoctorID` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `DoctorID_Index` (`DoctorID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Doctors table (42 rows)

```
CREATE TABLE `Doctors` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `DoctorName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Transactions table (~500,000 rows)

```
CREATE TABLE `Transactions` (
  `Description` text,
  `TransactionDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Amount` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PatientID` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `PatientID_Index` (`PatientID`),
  KEY `TransactionDate_Index` (`TransactionDate`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

This query takes about 1.5 seconds to execute for a single day. What could be going on here? It's not using the patients primary key index? How could this query be optimized further?

```
EXPLAIN SELECT P.ID, D.DoctorName, T.Description, T.Amount
FROM
    `Doctors` AS D
    INNER JOIN
        `Patients` AS P
        ON
            D.ID = P.DoctorID
    INNER JOIN
        `Transactions` AS T
        ON
            P.ID = T.PatientID
WHERE Date(T.TransactionDate) IN ('2017-03-30')

[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "select_type" : "SIMPLE",
        "table" : "P",
        "partitions" : null,
        "type" : "ALL",
        "possible_keys" : "PRIMARY",
        "key" : null,
        "key_len" : null,
        "ref" : null,
        "rows" : 13748,
        "filtered" : 100.00,
        "Extra" : "Using where"
    },
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "select_type" : "SIMPLE",
        "table" : "D",
        "partitions" : null,
        "type" : "eq_ref",
        "possible_keys" : "PRIMARY",
        "key" : "PRIMARY",
        "key_len" : "4",
        "ref" : "P.DoctorID",
        "rows" : 1,
        "filtered" : 100.00,
        "Extra" : null
    },
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "select_type" : "SIMPLE",
        "table" : "T",
        "partitions" : null,
        "type" : "ref",
        "possible_keys" : "PatientID_Index",
        "key" : "PatientID_Index",
        "key_len" : "5",
        "ref" : "P.ID",
        "rows" : 34,
        "filtered" : 100.00,
        "Extra" : "Using where"
    }
]
```

Comment: i would say you need to declare FOREIGN keys DoctorID and PatientId

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by doing this:

**1. Create the foreign keys.**

You need FKs between doctor and patient, and between patient and transaction. MySQL (unlike other databases) automatically creates the necessary indexes and speed up the queries.

```
alter table `Patients` add (
  constraint fk_patient_doctor foreign key (`DoctorId`) 
    references `Doctors` (`ID`)
);

alter table `Transactions` add (
  constraint fk_tx_patient foreign key (`PatientID`) 
    references `Patients` (`ID`)
);
```

**2. Create an index on transaction according to the date.**

```
create index ix_tx_date on `Transactions` (`TransactionDate`);
```

This will speed up the search by date, hopefully using a range scan insterad of a full table scan.

**3. Fix your query.**

As @UUeerdo says, instead of:

```
Date(T.TransactionDate) IN ('2017-03-30')
```

try:

```
T.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2017-03-30 00:00:00' AND '2017-03-30 23:59:59'
```

**4. Update MySQL statistics.**

```
analyze table `Transactions`;
analyze table `Patients`;
analyze table `Orders`;
```

Comment: Suppose that `T.TransactionDate < '2017-03-30 00:00:00'` -  How could you improve performance in that case?

Comment: Having an index on TransactionDate should help with queries using `BETWEEN`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, and possibly even `IN`. _(If `< '2017-03-30 00:00:00'` happens to be 5 baziillion rows, you're still not going to escape that you have a lot of data to work with.)_ _Also, foreign keys will not actually help with any of this; they only insure data integrity._

Answer (score 1):

Using any function on field values used in conditions can pretty much destroy performance (especially since it results in any indexes on those fields not being usable).

Instead of `Date(T.TransactionDate) IN ('2017-03-30')`

try
`T.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2017-03-30 00:00:00' AND '2017-03-30 23:59:59'`

Also, since you are filtering on `T.TransactionDate` and joining `T.PatientID`, having a single compound index on both with be more helpful than having separate indexes on each.

Answer (score 1):

The minimal change is to avoid hiding a column in a function (`DATE`).  I prefer this pattern:

```
WHERE T.TransactionDate >= '2017-03-30'
  AND T.TransactionDate  < '2017-03-30' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

That will let the Optimizer start with T, where the filtering can be done sooner.
You already have the necessary indexes.
Making the index on `TransactionDate` composite will not help.
The FKs do not add any performance.
`ANALYZE` is almost never needed for InnoDB tables.

Now I expect the `EXPLAIN` to show the tables in this order: T, P, D.  T will use the index on 'TransactionDate'; the others will use their `PRIMARY KEY`.  There should be no full-table-scan.

Comment: Is it possible to further optimize this query by avoiding the full table scan on Patients?

Comment: @3C41DC - See my added paragraph.